# Get name of standard action overriden in Visualforce contorller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller, salesforce-classic

I have a visualforce page that overrides both the 'New' and 'Edit' Buttons of a custom object. In my controller extension how can I get the name of the action that called this page ? I don't see anything in the [`StandardController`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_methods.htm), there are methods to redirect to the standard edit and view pages but nothing that will return the button clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's any standard way to do so, but you can utilize an approach here in your Extension's constructor to identify if the click was from New or Edit.

When you click on New button, that signifies that you are creating a new record and that it won't have an `Id` yet, whereas for Edit there will be always one. So checking that in the Extension will help you to identify the flow.

```
public class MyExtension {

    private MyObj__c abc;
    private String buttonClicked;

    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.abc = (MyObj__c) stdController.getRecord();

        buttonClicked = (abc.Id == null ? 'New' : 'Edit');
        // do something now
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Strictly speaking, the parentheses around the ternary expression is not necessary, since there's no ambiguity in the syntax.

Comment: @sfdcfox I agree. I just keep it for a better readability just to not confuse between `=` and `==` in the same statement.

Comment: I'll test it out, thanks !

Comment: I was already getting the record so perfect I'll just check if it's null. What's the abc for?

Comment: @SallyRothroat Ah, I missed that part. It's just a variable of type of the object which is fetched in the constructor, I have updated my answer. If you are already getting your record, then you just need to verify the `Id` and done.